# Ruby - Get USB VID/PID from serial port in a cross platform way

Tags: ruby, linux, macos, serial-port, usb

I'm writing a Ruby gem that will communicate to devices over serial via USB. There are a few different communication formats I need to deal with, the format is determined using a combination of PID/VID values.

I'd like for the gem to be cross platform (Linux/Mac/Windows), but I would settle for just Linux and Mac.

What is the most portable way in Ruby, using the fewest number of gems, to reliably detect USB PID/VID info of a serial port?

Comment: Do you need to handle the situation where there are multiple USB-to-serial adapters plugged into the same computer with different VID/PIDs and you need to know the VID/PID of a particular COM port (e.g. /dev/ttyACM3)?  That might be difficult.  Also, would it be an acceptable solution if the user of your software had to install a file in `/etc/udev.d/rules`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up parsing the output from command line programs under Mac & Linux, there doesn't seem to be a solution under windows with out writing a custom C extension.

Comment: I have Linux so please give more details how exactly you get the adapter VID and PID of usb bluetooth for example?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you need to get the VID and PID of a connected USB-to-Serial adapter that is associated with a particular COM port? Assuming that's the case, you should be able to do that with libusb. Looks like there is already some Ruby code for that: https://github.com/larskanis/libusb

Disclaimer - I haven't had to write anything crossplatform for USB and since I'm mainly a Windows developer I have used WinUSB. I just basing this on a quick look at the libusb API and it seems to have what you need.